# Joomla custom component + module URL

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I have written a custom component which lists a series of products. I created a complex search module which integrates with the component.
Now when I enter a search the resulting url is something like:
www.site.com/component/com_mycomp/?view=item&layout=list&categories[]=12&categories[]=5&etc.etc.

The problem with this is, that I have several other modules configured as "visible on all pages except..." which do not show up on this page, but they should. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a menu link and an associated itemid to make this work, then reference it in the url:

```
www.site.com/component/com_mycomp/?view=item&itemid=[new-item-id-#-from-menu]&categories[]=12&categories[]=5&etc.etc.
```

Comment: I don't think I understand.
What kind of menu should this be? The whole url (postvars) change with each search? I tried making a menuitem from my component and enter the "itemid" in you example to the url, but it does not work.

Comment: Perhaps I should make clear. My component has no relation whatsoever to any Joomla category or article. It is just some code that retrieves products from a database and displays them according to whatever search-terms have been input in the module. SO How can I make this into a menu since I have no reference to any menu-type?

Comment: Joomla is menu driven  - you need to add your component to a menu - probably main menu. In /administrator/ go to 'Menus' -> 'Main Menu' -> 'New'. Your component should show in the list, as long as you have a front end 'view'.

Comment: Ok, so I made a default.xml file in the view I need this menu for and then I created a menu item for this view. This still doesn't change my URL. Anything else I need to do?

Comment: AH, I got it. Itemid should be with a capital I and no need to include option/view vars. Thanks. I'll accept your answer as correct even though it isn't complete. (needed to create a custom menu type as well)